# How do we handle the factorials in the binomials/choice numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, factorial, catalan-numbers

Apparently the following is a known equality:

$\frac{1}{n + 1} {2n \choose n} = \frac{2n!}{n!(n + 1)!} = \frac{1}{2n + 1}{2n + 1 \choose n}$

but I can't really figure out how to produce the equality.
E.g.

$\frac{1}{n + 1} {2n \choose n} = \frac{1}{n + 1} \frac{(2n)!}{n! (2n - n)!} = \frac{1}{n + 1}  \frac{2n (2n - 1)!}{n!n!} = \frac{1}{n + 1}\frac{2n (2n - 1)!}{n(n-1)!n!}= \frac{1}{n + 1}\frac{2 (2n - 1)!}{(n-1)!n!}$
but then I am not sure how to proceed. Similar for the reverse direction.

How are the factorials here properly handled and we get this equality?

Comment: I think it is easier to show that both the left and the right hand side of your original equality simplify to the middle side, rather than trying to manipulate the left hand side into the right hand side.

Comment: The middle term should have a parentheses around the $2n$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: It does not have them in the book I am reading the formula. I thought that somehow we end up with $2n!$ actually, didn't occur to me that it could also be a typo

Comment: Regardless of what the book says, $2n!$ means $2 \cdot n!$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Yes I thought I should try to end up with $2n!$ since that is what the formula I read reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From left to right:

$\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{(2n)!}{n!(2n-n)!} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!} = \frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n+1)!n!} = \frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n} $

Comment: This makes sense. So it is a typo the $2n!$ in the text right? Because I was trying to figure out how to end up with $2n!$

Comment: Do you mean that parenthis are missing for $(2n)!$? Yes I think so otherwise because otherwise the first equality is wrong for n=2.